# Wordpress MySQL replication logins

Tags: mysql, load-balancing, wordpress, replication

I'm setting up a Wordpress site that is being load balanced across two servers, for various reasons the customer does not want a standalone database server. We've setup Master/Slave replication between the MySQL DB's which works well.

But whats the best way to deal with WP logins on the backend? Is there a way of preventing the customer logging into the WP backend on the SLAVE server? Obviously if they make changes when logged into the slave it won't be replicated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As you are using Master/Slave then don't allow writes on the slave MySQL DB and set it to read-only. You can also configure only master DB as DB_HOST in the wp-config.php or use HyperDB WP plugin to send read-only traffic to the slave DB.

Comment: Thanks Alex, thats helpful. I will have a look into using DB_HOST. If the load balancer sends the user to /wp-login on the slave though what would happen? Can we prevent that?

Comment: @user2377521 The load balancer doesn't send user to the MySQL DB slave, it send requests to WordPress which sends requests to MySQL DB. Which MySQL DB WordPress sends requests to depends on its configuration - DB_HOST in the `wp-config.php`. If you set DB_HOST to  master DB on all WordPress instances they will send requests to the master only.

Comment: Ok thats fine, but doesn't setting DB_HOST to master DB negate the point of having load balancing? If master DB goes down - will Wordpress then read SLAVE? Sorry if I am misunderstanding.

Comment: @user2377521 to utilise both master and slave DBs you can use HyperDB WP plugin. If  master fails this plugin will keep sending read-only queries to the salve but any write queries will fail and if your site needs to write to DB then it will fail.